# R: workaround for variable-width lookbehind

Tags: regex, r, lookbehind

Given this vector:

```
ba <- c('baa','aba','abba','abbba','aaba','aabba')'
```

I want to change the final `a` of each word to `i` except `baa` and `aba`.

I wrote the following line ...

```
gsub('(?<=a[ab]b{1,2})a','i',ba,perl=T)
```

but was told: *PCRE pattern compilation error 'lookbehind assertion is not fixed length' at ')a'*.

I looked around a little bit and apparently R/Perl can only lookahead for a variable width, not lookbehind. Any workaround to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the lookbehind alternative `\K` instead. This escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

**Quoted** — [**rexegg**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html)

> The key difference between \K and a lookbehind is that in PCRE, a lookbehind does not allow you to use quantifiers: the length of what you look for must be fixed. On the other hand, \K can be dropped anywhere in a pattern, so you are free to have any quantifiers you like before \K.

Using it in context:

```
sub('a[ab]b{1,2}\\Ka', 'i', ba, perl=T)
# [1] "baa"   "aba"   "abbi"  "abbbi" "aabi"  "aabbi"
```

Avoiding lookarounds:

```
sub('(a[ab]b{1,2})a', '\\1i', ba)
# [1] "baa"   "aba"   "abbi"  "abbbi" "aabi"  "aabbi"
```

Comment: Can I also ask if there is an equivalent of `\\K` in the other direction, i.e. resetting the end point of the reported match?

Comment: Yes, `\G` if I follow what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution **for the current case only**, when the only quantifier used is a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), may be using `stringr::str_replace_all` / `stringr::str_replace`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all(ba, '(?<=a[ab]b{1,2})a', 'i')
[1] "baa"   "aba"   "abbi"  "abbbi" "aabi"  "aabbi"
```

It works because `stringr` regex functions are based on [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) that features a *constrained-width* lookbehind:

> The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no `*` or `+` operators.)

So, you can't really use any kind of patterns inside ICU lookbehinds, but it is good to know you may use at least a limiting quantifier in it when you need to get overlapping texts within a known distance range.