# Replace every single character at the start of string that matches a regex pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to replace every single character in a string that matches a certain pattern. Take the following string

```
mystring <- c("000450")
```

I want to match all single zeros up to the first element that is non-zero. I tried something like

```
gsub("^0[^1-9]*", "x", mystring)
[1] "x450"
```

This expression replaces all the leading zeros with a single `x`. But instead, I want to replace all three leading zeros with `xxx`. The preferred result would be

```
[1] "xxx450"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use

```
mystring <- c("000450")
gsub("\\G0", "x", mystring, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "xxx450"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8Eaj8/1) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/8ZaJAW)

The `\\G0` regex matches `0` at the start of the string, and any `0` that only appears after a successful match.

**Details**

- `\G` - an anchor that matches ("asserts") the position at the start of the string or right after a successful match
- `0` - a `0` char.

Comment: Great, that works just fine! Why do you have to set `perl = TRUE`?

Comment: @RudiSophieson `\G` anchor is [not supported](https://ideone.com/wCh7yJ) by the default TRE regex falvor.