# Recursive regex in R for curly braces

Tags: r, regex, gsub, brackets, curly-braces

I have some text string in the following pattern.

```
x = "sdfwervd \calculus{fff}{\trt{sdfsdf} & \trt{sdfsdf} & \trt{sdfsdf} \\{} sdfsdf & sdfsdf & sefgse3 } aserdd wersdf sewtgdf"
```

1. I want to use regex to capture the text `"fff"` in the string `\calculus{fff}` and replace it with something else.
2. Further I want to capture the string between the first `{` after `\calculus{.+}` and it's corresponding closing curly brace `}`.

How to do this with regex in R ?

The following captures everything till last curly brace.

```
gsub("(\\calculus\\{)(.+)(\\})", "", x)
```

Comment: First of all, backslashes in your `x` string literals must be doubled (not sure as for `\\{}` though, `"\\{}"` => `\{}`). Then, the backslash before `c` can be matched with 2 literal backslashes, that is, 4 backslashes in the string literal. To match as few chars as possible, replace `.*` with `.*?`. `gsub` replaces the match with some replacement, you are removing the whole match, and only the match.

Comment: Can try something like gsub("(\\calculus\\{)(.+)(\\})", "(\\calculus\\{)(###)(\\})", x)

Comment: See http://rextester.com/MQHT68999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second task you can use a recursive approach in combination with `regmatches()` and `gregexpr()` in base `R`:

```
x <- c("sdfwervd \\calculus{fff}{\\trt{sdfsdf} & \\trt{sdfsdf} & \\trt{sdfsdf} \\{} sdfsdf & sdfsdf & sefgse3 } aserdd wersdf sewtgdf")

pattern <- "\\{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*\\}"
(result <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = TRUE)))
```

---

This yields a list of the found submatches:

```
[[1]]
[1] "{fff}"                                                                          
[2] "{\\trt{sdfsdf} & \\trt{sdfsdf} & \\trt{sdfsdf} \\{} sdfsdf & sdfsdf & sefgse3 }"
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vduvHi/1).

Comment: How to remove the curly braces from the second pattern alone and modify it ? `\\calculus{fff}{anystring}` to `\\calculus{fff}##anystring$$` https://regex101.com/r/vduvHi/3

Comment: Either use `substr(your_string, 1, nchar(your_string) - 1)` or captured groups.