# paste specific text to strings that do not have it

Tags: r, paste

I would like to paste `"miR"` to strings that do not have `"miR"` already, and skipping those that have it.

paste("miR", ....)

in

```
c("miR-26b", "miR-26a", "1297", "4465", "miR-26b", "miR-26a")
```

out

```
c("miR-26b", "miR-26a", "miR-1297", "miR-4465", "miR-26b", "miR-26a")
```

Answer (score 3):

One way could be by removing "miR" if it is present in the beginning of the string using `sub` and pasting it to every string irrespectively.

```
paste0("miR-", sub("^miR-","", x))

#[1] "miR-26b"  "miR-26a"  "miR-1297" "miR-4465" "miR-26b"  "miR-26a"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("miR-26b", "miR-26a", "1297", "4465", "miR-26b", "miR-26a")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vec <- c("miR-26b", "miR-26a", "1297", "4465", "miR-26b", "miR-26a")

sub("^(?!miR)(.*)$", "miR-\\1", vec, perl = T)

#[1] "miR-26b"  "miR-26a"  "miR-1297" "miR-4465" "miR-26b"  "miR-26a"
```

---

If you want to learn more:

- type `?sub` into R console
- learn regex, have a closer look at `negative look ahead`, `capturing groups` [LEARN REGEX](http://regex101.com)
- I've used `perl = T` because I get an error if I don't. [READ MORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240375/regular-expressions-in-base-r-perl-true-vs-the-default-pcre-vs-tre)

Comment: To make your answer more valuable, could you please explain briefly, in words, what sub() does and why it solves the question? Perhaps extend it with why you use the argument perl=T.