# Remove repeated elements in a string with R

Tags: r, regex, string

I plan to remove repeated elements (each containing two or more characters) from strings. For example, from "aaa" I expect "aaa", from "aaaa" I expect "aa", from "abababcdcd" I epxect "abcd", from "cdababcdcd" I expect "cdabcd".

I tried `gsub("(.{2,})\\1+","\\1",str)`. It works in cases 1-3, but fails in case 4. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it fails for `"cdababcdcd"`? See https://regex101.com/r/Cwki9E/1

Comment: use `perl = TRUE` as argument

Comment: Yes, looks like [TRE does not cope with this task](https://ideone.com/kapxyZ).

Comment: Beware that this regex is dastardly inefficient. it runs fine on extremely short strings but even on moderately long strings of a certain structure it may take very long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to rely on the PCRE or ICU regex engines, rather than TRE.

Use either base R `gsub` with `perl=TRUE` (it uses [PCRE regex engine](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt)) and `"(?s)(.{2,})\\1+"` pattern, or a `stringr::str_replace_all()` (it uses [ICU regex engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)) with the same pattern:

```
> x <- "cdababcdcd"
> gsub("(?s)(.{2,})\\1+", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "cdabcd"
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all(x, "(?s)(.{2,})\\1+", "\\1")
[1] "cdabcd"
```

The `(?s)` flag is necessary for `.` to match any char including line break chars (in TRE regex, `.` matches all chars by default).

**DETAILS**

[TRE regex](https://laurikari.net/tre/about/) is not good at handling "pathological" cases that are mostly related to backtracking, which directly involves quantifiers (I bolded some parts):

> The matching algorithm used in **TRE uses linear worst-case time in the length of the text being searched, and quadratic worst-case time in the length of the used regular expression. In other words, the time complexity of the algorithm is *O(M2N)*, where *M* is the length of the regular expression and *N* is the length of the text.** The used space is also quadratic on the length of the regex, but does not depend on the searched string. This quadratic behaviour occurs only on pathological cases which are probably very rare in practice.
>
> **Predictable matching speed**
> Because of the matching algorithm used in TRE, **the maximum time consumed by any `regexec()` call is always directly proportional to the length of the searched string. There is one exception: if back references are used, the matching may take time that grows exponentially with the length of the string.** This is because [matching back references is an NP complete problem](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/NPC-3SAT.html), and almost certainly requires exponential time to match in the worst case.

In those cases when TRE has trouble calculating all possibilities of matching a string it does not return any match, the string is returned *as is*. Hence, there is no changes in the `gsub` call.

Answer (score 2):

As easy as: 
`gsub("(.{2,})\\1+","\\1",str, perl = T)`

Comment: *Don’t* use `T` and `F`, which can be redefined. Use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead (which cannot).

Comment: Can you please explain this behavior? Why TRE can't deal with this task?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The answer lies in TRE’s [“About” page](https://laurikari.net/tre/about/): “The matching algorithm used in TRE uses linear worst-case time in the length of the text being searched”. In other words, TRE can’t do this by design, although the text goes on to qualify this for the case of backreferences. Nevertheless, it seems that the algorithm will never backtrack in this case.

Comment: Can you add a little more context, or description, as to why this works, where the OP's solution failed?  This can help other users understand the issue and solution, so they can solve similar problems on their own in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: It works like a charm, on UTF-8 characters, too. Thank you, César Arquero.