# How can I extract a string rowwise using regex?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a column `filename` in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
/testData/THQ/TAIRATE.20030314.190000.tif
/testData/THQ/TAIRATE.20030314.200000.tif
/testData/THQ/TAIRATE.20030314.210000.tif
/testData/THQ/TAIRATE.20030314.220000.tif
```

And I want to extract the timestamp from this and store it as another column. But I am not familiar with Regex. So far I have gotten to this:

```
tdat %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(timestamp = str_extract(as.character(filename), "[^//TAIRATE]+$")) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

#### Result

```
.20030314.190000.tif
.20030314.200000.tif
.20030314.210000.tif
.20030314.220000.tif
```

### Expected result

```
20030314190000
20030314200000
20030314210000
20030314220000
```

**Question**: How can I write the correct regex or is there a better way?

Comment: Try `str_extract(as.character(filename), "(?<=TAIRATE\\.)\\d+")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! But this is removing everything after the dot. Getting `20030314`

Comment: True, then what about `str_replace(as.character(filename), ".*TAIRATE\\.(\\d+)\.(\\d+).*", "\\1\\2")`? This will have a side effect: if there is no match found, you will end up with the whole file name unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

`str_extract` and other such functions are vectorized you don't need row-wise.

In this case, you can do this in base R using `sub`.

```
sub('.*TAIRATE\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+).*', '\\1\\2', df$filename)
#[1] "20030314190000" "20030314200000" "20030314210000" "20030314220000"
```

Comment: @maximusdooku Same note as in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405549/how-can-i-extract-a-string-rowwise-using-regex#comment108626908_61405549): This will have a side effect: if there is no match found, you will end up with the whole file name unchanged

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for that cautionary note! Also, as a sidenote - what's a good resource to learn just enough about regex to make it work? I always avoided learning it.

Comment: @maximusdooku I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: @maximusdooku For R, also see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251004/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly less elegant than @akrun's solution but this one works too:

```
paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(filename, "[0-9]+")), collapse = "")
```

Data:

```
filename <- "/testData/THQ/TAIRATE.20030314.190000.tif"
```