# How do you replace a specific character in a string in R with an existing character?

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, stringr

I have a tibble with a variable df$sec which is a vector of two character strings.

```
sec <- c("21", "33", "24", "7-", "32", "1-")
```

The character set 7- and 1- should be 07 and 01.

Using {stringr}

```
df %>% 
  mutate(section = str_replace(string=sec, pattern = ".-$", "0?")) %>% 
  select(section)
```

This returns:   21,33,24,0?, 32, 0?
How do I return the characters 7- and 1- as 07 and 01?

Comment: Try `str_replace(string=sec, pattern = "^(\\d)-$", "0\\1")`

Comment: I am trying to understand the grouping.  I've just ordered a couple of books on regex.  If you have suggestions, please post.  Thank you again.

Comment: I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.
For R, also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251004/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_replace(string=sec, pattern = "^(\\d)-$", "0\\1")
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d)` - capturing group #1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the string captured in this group): a digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `$` - end of string.